# Cannot edit brand new UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I just made a new Swift project, put some text fields and a couple buttons in it, and when I start the app I cannot seem to be able to edit the text fields. Like the text fields are not taking any input. Any of them!

At the moment this is my only code. There should be nothing wrong with it. I literally ran the same code on another app and everything worked perfectly.

```
@IBOutlet weak var monthlyTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var annualL: UILabel!

var year = Double()

@IBAction func calculateAnnB(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let monthlyInc = Double(monthlyTF.text!){
        year = 12*monthlyInc
        annualL.text = "\(year)"
    }else{
        annualL.text = "That's not a number!"
    }
}
```

There are other buttons and text fields in the app but I have not linked them yet because I didn't get to that part. I just wanted to test it piece by piece. Should I link them all first and then try?

It should be a really simple project. I don't know why I keep getting stuck on stupid technicalities like these.

Answer (score 1):

Try what dinosaysrawr said, and also make sure **User Interaction Enabled** is set to **true** in the storyboard (under "View" in the Attributes Inspector).

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting and reinstalling the UITextField in the storyboard

Edit: Also, make sure that the textField is enabled in the "Attributes Inspector" under "Control". If it's not enabled, it'll be grayed out and you can't tap on it to edit it